# How to visualize calendar dates (in Keynote? Or Numbers?)

Tags: keynote, numbers

I am having trouble visualizing dates in a presentation. [This image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l717wwur18b3w7h/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-21%20at%206.17.13%20PM.png?dl=0) is a good example of what I'm hoping to have, but I would like a way to make the slide from a table of dates (rather than making each box by hand, which is what happened here).

Any suggestions? I can use Numbers, Keynote, or Excel or PowerPoint for Mac. Also open to other software options that would do this.

Comment: you are right, that one is way to busy, to many colors.

Comment: I would use 1 color and place the α β γ in the boxes, it is clear that that is the order anyway.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thanks for the suggestion. Any ideas on how to make the chart automatically from spreadsheet data?

Comment: I only know and use Excel :)

Comment: @Buscar웃: Any idea what to use to do it in Excel? I have Excel too, but wouldn't know where to look or what to google for to find how to do something like this. Thanks!

Comment: see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the Office "gantt chart" feature to present your data.

> Options for making a Gantt chart
>
> Although it is not a graphical tool by design, it is possible, with
>   quite a bit of formatting, to make a Gantt chart in Excel. You can do
>   this by turning your project tables into an Excel Gantt chart using
>   Excel's bar graph functionality. It is also possible and significantly
>   easier to create much more graphical and more manageable Gantt charts
>   in PowerPoint, such as the one above. You can do this by simply
>   pasting your Excel project tables into a PowerPoint add-in called
>   Office Timeline.

There are many templates available [here](https://www.officetimeline.com/gantt-chart-excel).

[image: gant chart]